# Which sentence (out of four) is Grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

I want to inform the policy holder of the loan balance on the policy. I am writing a letter and want to pick one correct sentence.

1. "No outstanding loan due on your policy."
2. "No outstanding loan is due on your policy."
3. "No outstanding loan balance due on your policy."
4. "No outstanding loan balance is due on your policy."

Comment: 1 and 3 are not sentences. I am not sure what you are trying to say. Do you mean that there is no loan payment due, but there will be next month? Do you mean that there is no more to pay on the loan, ever?

Comment: Yes, there is no more to pay on the loan, ever.

Comment: [There is] no outstanding amount due on your policy. Without there is, it would be used as a shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#4 would be the correct option.

When using the word *loan*, it generally refers to the process of availing or providing a loan. Since you want to inform the holder about the amount left, you can say *No outstanding loan balance is due on your policy*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it would be clearer to re-write it as one of

> No further payments are due on your loan
> You have completely paid off your loan

Comment: Yes, because “no balance due” means only that no payment is required *this month*.